# Is it necessary to set up a reverse proxy in front of a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, reverse-proxy, kubernetes-ingress

I have set up a kubernetes cluster using kubeadm on a server, which is using an ingress controller (nginx) and this is working as intended. However, I used to deploy a nginx reverse proxy when I was using docker and to forward traffic to the containers. I have read that the ingress controller embarks a reverse proxy but I am not sure if it is sufficient and how to configure it (like IP ban when too many requests are sent in 1 s, ...).

I am aware that it can be done by modifying the port of the cluster and forwarding the traffic from the reverse proxy to the ingress controller but I don't know if it has any utility.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more control over your inbound traffic, you can test multiple ingresses, not only Nginx. It will depend on the purpose of your requirement, although Nginx supports [rate-limit](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rate-limiting). I suggest test others ingresses but try to install [metal-lb](https://metallb.universe.tf/) firstly. So you can assign a specific Loadbalancer IP for each ingress.